# Multi picklist value in formula

Tags: workflow, multi-select

I am trying to implement a use case here.
I have a date field and a multi picklist field.

Multi picklist has all the days of week from sunday to monday.

Now, i have to get the day from the date field and check whether that exists in the multi picklist field.

Can we use multi picklist field in Workflow formulas.

```
CASE(
MOD(DATEVALUE(date field) - DATE(1900, 1, 6), 7),
0, "Sunday",
1, "Monday",
2, "Tuesday",
3, "Wednesday",
4, "Thursday",
5, "Friday",
6, "Saturday", "Error")
```

Am using the above formula to get the day from date field.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me,

**Formula 1:**

Use your formula in the question, identify the day of the week.

I compared today to get the day of the week.

```
CASE( MOD( today() - DATE(1900, 1, 7), 7), 0, "Sunday", 1, "Monday", 2, "Tuesday", 3, 
"Wednesday", 4, "Thursday", 5, "Friday", 6, "Saturday","Error")
```

**Formula 2:** 
Create another checkbox formula and check if multiselect value includes the day and  same as the  day of the week from formula1 then the value is true.

```
OR(
AND(INCLUDES(mulsel__c,"Sunday"),day_of_the_week__c =="Sunday"),
AND(INCLUDES(mulsel__c,"Monday"),day_of_the_week__c =="Monday"),
AND(INCLUDES(mulsel__c,"Tuesday"),day_of_the_week__c =="Tuesday"),
AND(INCLUDES(mulsel__c,"Wednesday"),day_of_the_week__c =="Wednesday"),
AND(INCLUDES(mulsel__c,"Thursday"),day_of_the_week__c =="Thursday"),
AND(INCLUDES(mulsel__c,"Friday"),day_of_the_week__c =="Friday"),
AND(INCLUDES(mulsel__c,"Saturday"),day_of_the_week__c =="Saturday")
)
```